# How to include values from other fields in error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I am using Parsely to validate a field that depends on another field. I am also using Bootstrap tooltips to display the errors.

I created a custom validator to validate an input that has a value greater than or equal to another input value. I wish to display the error message with the value from the first textbox when the user has made a mistake.

```
var v="";
window.ParsleyValidator.addValidator('gte', 
    function (value, requirement) {
        v=$(requirement).val();
        alert(v);
        return parseFloat(value) >= parseFloat($(requirement).val());
    }, 32)
    .addMessage('en', 'gte', 'This value should be greater or equal to '+v);
```

In this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sevren/zawx26h7/33/) is a complete example.

To test this put the value 2 in the first textbox and 1 in the second. The correct error message should be

> This value should be greater or equal to 2.

If I set the variable 'v' to be equal to something it does append in the error message. If I try to set it to the `$(requirement).val()` it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should update the catalog to get it done :)

Here is the updated fiddle for you:

> http://jsfiddle.net/zawx26h7/34/

And only the change i did in validator script below is the same

```
//var v = "";
window.ParsleyValidator.addValidator('gte',
function (value, requirement) {
    window.ParsleyValidator.catalog.en.gte = 'This value should be greater or equal to ' + $(requirement).val();
    return parseFloat(value) >= parseFloat($(requirement).val());
}, 32)
    //.addMessage('en', 'gte', 'This value should be greater or equal to ' + v);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using `v` in a different context. It should be noted that `v` is setted correctly in the `addValidator`. You are trying to using outside that function in `addMessage`.

You can resolve this issue by setting the message manually, like this:

```
var v="";
window.ParsleyValidator
    .addValidator('gte', function (value, requirement) {
        v = $(requirement).val();

        if (parseFloat(value) < parseFloat(v)) {
            window.ParsleyValidator.addMessage('en', 'gte', 
                   'This value should be greater or equal to ' + v);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }, 32);
```

Instead of passing the message in the definition of the validator, you can add the message inside the actual validation with `window.ParsleyValidator.addMessage`.

You can test it you [**this updated jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/q07r36p1/2/).

---

I want to refer two things:

1. [This issue on GitHub](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/644) details the same situation as yours and the solution that I've presented is based on this issue.
2. Parsley has a [Parsley Extras](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#extras) in the docs. These extras provide additional validations such as `Greater than or equal to`. I've never used them but if you want I guess is just a matter of including the `comparison.js` file that can be [downloaded from GitHub](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/blob/master/src/extra/validator/comparison.js).However, I'm not sure how the messages will behave.